# Why must an AdvP have at least one AdvP as a Daughter Node?

Tags: syntax-trees

<sub>Source: p 78, *Syntax, A Generative Introduction* (3 ed, 2012) by Andrew Carnie.

Though I am only on Chapter 4 at the time of this post, I cannot wait until Chapter 6 to understand the following.</sub>

[image]

> Here is a common mistake to avoid: Notice that the AdvP rule specifies that its modifier is another AdvP: AdvP  ⟶ (AdvP) Adv. The rule does NOT say *AdvP  ⟶ (Adv) Adv, so you will never get trees of the form shown in (28) [see above]:
>
> You might find the tree in (27) a little confusing. There are two Advs and two AdvPs. In order to understand that tree a little better, let’s introduce a new concept: ***heads***. We’ll spend much more time on heads in chapters 6 and 7, but here’s a first pass: The head of a phrase is the word that gives the phrase its category.

I reread pp 78-79, but still do not understand why 28 is wrong and only 27 is correct.
What is the main idea here? How does the concept of Heads resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AdvP immediately dominated two Advs, what would the head of the phrase be? There must be one distinct head, and in 28) this could be either of the Advs, there would be no way to clearly decide which node is the head of the phrase. Therefore, you specify which adverb should be the head of the AdvP (here it is *quickly*, because this is the "main" adverb that is again modified by another adverb) and the issue is resolved, since the AdvP containing the adverb *very* can in no way be the head of the adverb phrae.

Comment: It's confusing to put 'very' and 'quickly' in the same syntax category Adv, since one is a quality of an action and the other is an intensifier of a quality.  Each is adverbial (nested), with 'quickly' modifying the verb and 'very' modifying 'quickly', but 'very very', 'quickly quickly' and 'quickly very' are not valid complete adverbial phrases.

Comment: I think the point that disturbs you is that the term "adverb" implies it modifies a verb. But this is not necessarily so; an adverb can modify anything, from verbs to adjectives and even adverbs, The trouble is that you don't have a terminological distinction between modifiers of an action and modifiers of a modifier of an action, but as long as there's no alternative terminology for words explicitely modifying adverbs (at least I'm not aware of any - call them *adadverbs*? ;) ), I guess you need to live with the fact that "adverb" is a label that doesn't tell much about the word's semantics.

Comment: I think that the fact it modifies an adverb rather than a verb/action is alreay well-visible from the syntactic structure, where *very* is an AdvP to an AdvP and not an AdvP to a VP, thereby clearly modifying a modifier itself rather than the action. The labeling shouldn't disturb too much then; both the, admittedly vague, terms *adveb* and *adverbial* are rather meant to denote the function of such phrases and not primarily a word category (as the name *ad-verb* would suggest), which I think is not too unuseful in a tree that wants to emphasise grammatical relations rather than word classes.

Comment: BTW, I recently had a similar discussion about the *adverb* / *adverbial* terminology [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/18941/13238), and am basically aware of the problem, but don't know of any alternative, more meaningful terminology and therfore make use of the standard categories.

Comment: I see your points.  I prefer the term 'intensifier' for words that modify qualities (quality as in 'adjective').  I think the category 'adverb' should be broken into intensifiers (very), temporals (soon), and qualities (quickly), so that parsers can state that intensifiers precede the intensified.

Comment: For parsers and other practical applications, such a disctinction surely is useful; in purely theoretical discussions which the current example is, explanations usually seek a lot more universality and tend to subsume a lot of stuff under the same notions for reasons of generality and simplicity - which doesn't always give the most satisfying results ;)

Comment: So, for 'theorizing', we can require these 'stick' tree limbs.  This just shows that the theory is weak, and you'll need to flesh out those branches later.

Comment: I didn't mean to take a position that extreme; since we can, as you say, flesh out the branches later, I wouldn't say we can judge at this point already that the theory is weak - the example as I understood it is meant so serve as an illustration for the general rules of phrase structure trees (there must be an identifiable head), where the exact labeling of the adverb or not-so-much-adverb nodes is a decision that needs not yet be finally disucssed at this point. ...

Comment: ... I haven't read the book myself, but such (introductory) syntactic theory works usually don't put so much focus on the more fine-grained problems of the involved elements, which doesn't mean they claim such fine-grainedness doesn't exist or couldn't be made if one was more interested in a detailed analysis or practical applications. Whether or not you'd want to include this depends on the purpose, and I think that for the intention of the example in the original question, simplicity overweighted a most precise terminological classification.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I wonder whether it is harder to separate the grains initially, or to ask students to accept the dummy tree nodes.  Lumping intensifiers with adverbs is like lumping determiners with adjectives.

Comment: Re-thinking something you have previously assumed to be different and reasoning why the previous analysis was insufficient or inadequate often helps to understand better why things work they way they work. But I don't know what exactly the author's intentions were, and basically would agree that one should avoid using unclear or even incorrect examples for basic notions that then need to be dissolved later, this can make the theory appear somewhat sketchy.